# Container Won't span the height of page when sidebar is added

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm putting together a Tumblr layout and I'm running into a snag. I got everything working fine, but as soon as I added my sidebar, the container stopped expanding the height of the page. It stops right under the end of the sidebar and I'm not sure why when previously it expanded the width of the content section.

URL: http://nellyswritingroom.tumblr.com/

Structural CSS:

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 60px 30px 60px;
    width: 900px;
}
#main {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#content {
    width: 620px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
aside {
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 60px;
}


header#top {
    text-align: center;
    height: 293px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

header#top h1{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:285px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}

header#top h2 {
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:285px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML skeleton:

```
<div id="container">
    <header id="top>
        <h1>
        content
        </h1>
        <h2>
            content
        </h2>
    </header>

    <nav>Nav Goes here</nav>

    <section id="content">
        Content on the left
    </section>

    <aside>
        Sidebar Content
    </aside>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe it has to do with your float. that's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a clear: both; after the aside element closes.

So, after:

```
<aside>
    Testing
</aside>
```

Add:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

And you will see the issue should be resolved.

Of course, it would be better to make a .clear CSS class and call that, rather than using inline CSS.

Comment: I tried creating a class, but when I called <div class="clear">, it didn't work. Is this the proper CSS:  

.clear{
clear: both;
}

Comment: That is the proper CSS. I see the .clear class in http://www.onedirectionconnection.com/newstyle.css

Answer (score 0):

Because `#content` is floated it is no longer part of the layout, thus the parent is only sized to contain the sidebar.

You should remove the `float:left` from the content section, and apply `float:right` to the `aside`. This does assume the content is always longer than the sidebar - if this isn't the case you can either employ a clearing element below both elements, or float the container as well, or look into `display:block` or relative positioning to position them next to eachother.